# How to set gmaps to open at my location?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Trying to get gmaps to open at my location but its not working for me:
Edited: there was supposed to be nothing at the lat and lng, also added the div where this map is presented. I thought I could create a map with no coordinates, but have it go to my location right after creation using the geolocation function. How can i write this so that the map is created at my location without hardcoding the coordinates?

```
<div id="outputMap"></div>



<script>


      var map;

      map = new GMaps({
          div: '#outputMap',
          lat: 0,
          lng: 0,
      });

      GMaps.geolocate({      
        function(position) {
        map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      }});

      map.zoomOut();
```

Comment: So, where does it open relative to where you want it to open? Are you aware that the map.zoomOut() will be performed before, not after, map.setCenter(...)?

Comment: What is stored in `lats` and `lngs` and why don't you initialize the map at the geolocation you desire?

Answer (score 0):

When using the official JS API, an initial `zoom` value is required:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 14});
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        map.setCenter(pos);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```